# Rooting without using sqrt in Swift

Tags: swift, for-loop, sqrt

I am trying to approach the rooting Swift exercise without using sqrt() method.

My idea was following:

```
import Foundation


    func rooting(number:Int) -> Int {
    
            for i in 1...100 {
                if i * i == number {
                    var Root = i
                    break }
                
                return Root //here
            }
        return Root //here
    }
            
            print(rooting(number:9))
```

But on the lines I left comments for you, I get `Cannot find 'Root' in scope` error. When I try to initialize root as an integer before I run the function, the function either uses the value I initialized the Root variable with or I get some errors if I try to initialize it as an optional integer or an empty array.

What's wrong with my thinking here?

Comment: What is the value of `Root` if `if` fails? in other words where do you set `Root` for `else`?

Comment: I started creating this function with throwing errors first, but then it was even more complicated, so I figured to simplify it and resolve this issue first with safe input, @loremipsum.

In the full program, the error is handled with enum and do - try - catch syntax :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is home task question

Comment: You are over complicating. `Root` doesn't exist for `else` or the `return` it was created inside the `if`. Where could you put the declaration so `Root` is available for `if` and `else` and for the `return`?

Comment: And what's wrong if I need help with it @Cy-4AH?
People come here when they have problems with the task in their job they get paid for...

Comment: SO isn't for homework, that is why I am not giving you the answer.

Comment: Yes, I created it before for-in loop before, @loremipsum, but then comes the initialisation problem.
Either you initialise it as an Integer, an optional Integer or an Array (I'm yet to try it with tuple). The two latter throw errors, the first one get the function to use the initial value instead of the one returned from the for-in loop.

Comment: @Cy-4AH the question isn't for us to do it for them, the question is why they aren't getting it

Comment: The main problem here as I see it is that you don't understand the concept of _scope_, a variable can only be accessed in the same scope it was declared and a scope can be a lot of things like an app, a struct, a function or something like an if clause or a loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so here's your code after I aligned it.

```swift
import Foundation

func rooting(number: Int) -> Int {
  for i in 1...100 {
    if i * i == number {
      var Root = i
      break
    }
    return Root
  }
  return Root
}

print(rooting(number: 9))
```

The problem is that you are creating the `Root` variable in a scope that ends before you try to use the variable. Essentially, the `Root` variable only exists in the following segment:

```swift
import Foundation

func rooting(number: Int) -> Int {
  for i in 1...100 {
    if i * i == number {
      var Root = I //Root variable starts existing
      break
    } //Root variable no longer exists
    return Root
  }
  return Root
}

print(rooting(number: 9))
```

This is because it is *scoped* to the `if` statement. To solve this *specific* problem, you could change your code to this:

```swift
import Foundation

func rooting(number: Int) -> Int {
  for i in 1...100 {
    if i * i == number {
      return i
    }
  }
}

print(rooting(number: 9))
```

since you don't do anything with `Root` other than return it. Of course, this still won't work, as you aren't guaranteed to return anything (what if `number` is 8?), and you said that the function will always return an `Int`.

---

Here's a quick example of an implementation of a rooting function:

```swift
import Foundation

func rooting(number: Int) -> Int? {
  guard number > 0 else { return nil }
  for i in 0...(number/2) {
    if i * i == number {
      return i
    }
  }
  return nil
}

print(rooting(number: 9))
```

If the number has a square root, it will be returned; otherwise, the function returns `nil`.